# Nuxt Firefox scrolls to bottom of page

Tags: firefox, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt and decided to give it a shot and to make a webpage.

However I have this weird thing where when I click on a link the Firefox browser shows the page at the bottom, while Chrome scrolls automaticly up.

This only happens with Firefox and have no idea what is causing it, does anyone have a idea?

Ps: I am using the footer component in the default lay-out

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that when i go directly to the url Firefox shows the top at the page as it should, but when using nuxt link it loads and shows the bottom